# Real froms of complex unipotent groups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a real linear group such that $G^{\mathbb C}$ is its complexification group in $GL_n(\mathbb C)$. Let $U$ be a unipotent complex Lie subgroup of $G^{\mathbb C}$. Does $U$ have a real form i.e. $(U\cap G)^{\mathbb C}=U$?

Comment: I doubt it. Try taking $G = SU_2$, a compact group. The complexification is $SL_2(\Bbb C)$, but the unipotent subgroups of this should have trivial intersection with $G$.